# How to convert into date format?

Tags: ms-access, datetime, vba

Using Access 2003

Date Column datatype is text

Table1

Date

```
20090528
20090529
20090530
20090502
20090504
```

Expected Output

```
28-May-2009
29-May-2009
30-May-2009
02-May-2009
04-May-2009
```

...,

How to make a query for the Expected Output Date format?

Comment: if you have a column which stores dates, you probably really should be using a column with date time as it's type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As VBA code** - you could wrap it as a function

```
Dim strMyDate As String
Dim dteDate As Date

strDate = "20090528"
dteDate = DateSerial(Left(strDate, 4), Mid(strDate, 5, 2), Right(strDate, 2))
MyStr = Format(dteDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
Debug.Print MyStr
```

**As a Data type in a Table** - If you append the data to a table where the field is Date/Time formatted then you can specify the format on the Form / Table i.e. at output time.

Comment: It is best not to use a User Defined Function (UDF), if you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

I find that Cdate does not work for me.

```
Format(DateSerial(Left(Field1, 4), Mid(Field1, 2, 2), Right(Field1, 2)), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

CDate should do what you want...

Comment: Please explain how CDate() can convert a string of the form "20090504" into a date.